# SVN copy to Local work space should preserve svn history

Tags: svn, copy

My requirement is such a way that I have 1 maven Project in my work space  say project1 which I checked out from svn

I created a new maven project project2 and I want to copy the packages from project 1 to Project 2, when I did a normal copy I am not getting the svn history of files

is there any way of getting svn history of copied files in project2.

Answer (score 0):

If you did an `svn cp` from project1 to project2, you do have the history... your client is likely stopping on the copy/rename when showing the log.

how exactly did you copy it?

This is entirely unrelated to your question... but you should really think hard about reorganizing the code into some shared libraries rather than duplicating it.  You've already got maven so this shouldn't be to hard.  You're going to have fix bugs twice.